# How do import numpys on Jupiter notebook?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, jupyter-notebook

Hi everyone im currently facing problems with importing NumPy in jupyter notebook.

My first line of code was `import numpy as np` it resulted into giving me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8b972f5c2406> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy as np
```

After that my second option was to install NumPy which I did using `!pip3 install numpy` and that gave me Requirement already satisfied: NumPy in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.19.0)`

Can someone let me know if I should re-download pip or something is wrong in my files? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check what version of python is your jupyter running.

Its highly likely that its running python 2.x.

If so, try using `!pip install numpy` instead of `!pip3 install numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your Terminal, and execute `!pip install numpy` or `pip3 install numpy` depending on which version of Python you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, check for your python version using below command:

```
python --version
```

if you are using version 2 or 3:

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

if you are using version 3 or higher:

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

This way you know about where the package will be installed